# How to make fabric canvas lightweight

Tags: load, fabricjs

Currently, I am working on one image processing editor, and I have an issue about hang of canvas when it is too large.

My fabric js version is 1.7.22

When I add a large image in canvas and apply multiple filters, my canvas takes lots of time to render.

Please give me some tips for reducing the load.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry for late response.
I can't generate this type of fiddle, when I try to make a fiddle, all are perfect without loading, but in my project, it was take a load.

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind that is on version 1.7.22 filters are executed on the cpu and the main thread.
On version 2 there are filters on webgl that are noticeably faster.

So my answer is that if you are mostly about filtering, please switch to version 2.4.4